# how to read in csv files in c with multiple delimiters

Tags: c, csv, delimiter, scanf

Was looking to read in a CSV file in c using fscanf.

CSV File:
John paul 
Mike 
Ronny Baldwin

Structure definition

```
typedef struct{
 char *name;
}keydata_t;
```

This is how I am reading in the CSV files

```
keydata_t*read_key(FILE* fp)
{
char name[65];
if (fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", name) == 1 ) {
    keydata_t *k = (keydata_t*)malloc(sizeof(keydata_t));
    printf("%s\n", name);
    k->name = strdup(name);
    return k;
}
return NULL;
}
```

This is where I call the read function which is inside the main function.

```
int max_index = index; //index value is 
for (int i =0; i < max_index; i++)
{
    keyt = read_key(keyfile);
    search_tree(root,keyt);//root is my bst which consists of all the strings. 
    printf("%d\n", i);

}
```

search function passes the rootptr which is the head and finds all the key values that matches keyt.

My mistake is that keyt in the read function it only reads John paul and returns it. How do I use fscanf correctly so that I could store all the names within the file.

Comment: If you want to read a whole line, don't use `scanf` (or its siblings), use a functions whose purpose it is to read a whole line, like [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: Strictly speakin that's not really CSV, rather just a text file where each line is a record, so just read each line?

Comment: As for your problem, are you reading the file to add the names to your tree? or do you want a list of names to search for in your tree?

Comment: @stijn : it is a csv file

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Well I am reading the names and then it goes into search to check if it exists in the BST created in the insert function. But I have to check all three and not just the first name John paul

Comment: Usually if the delimiter isn't a comma/semicolon/tab/... it's not called CSV, though that might just be me

Comment: **CSV : Comma Separated Values** there is no comma in your file, ergo it is not a CSV file

Comment: @pmg : So then how would I read in these names?

Comment: Dave, read the lines of the file with fgets() as @JoachimPileborg suggests; and afterwards remove the trailing ENTER.

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` --> `"%[^\n]%*c"` : Newline must be consumed for the next input.